# Multi-level image gallery in WordPress

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress site for a shoe company. Each shoe comes in different colors. On the main shoe page(s) there will be one color. When the user clicks on the shoe or a link they will drill down to see all colors. Both pages will have some meta information about the shoes such as price, SKU, as well as a download link for the image. 
The place where I am seeking some advice, is how can I automate this process? Best case would be to FTP a directory structure of images and have WP and PHP generate the appropriate code based upon that structure. Perhaps another way would be to user JSON. I would like to have this process automated because potentially there are hundreds of images which change every season. I am not asking anyone to write this code for me :) Just help me go in the right direction. 
[image: Blue boxes represent pages, black boxes are images and meta information]

Comment: A demo or example code of what you have would be quite helpful! Never-the-less, a PHP script would do it best, but it seems you already have the structure in mind. It's just a case of a few database queries and working out where you currently are in that process

Comment: I uploaded a flow. Not sure if that helps or not. I don't have any code written for this part of the site — I am just trying to get started in the right direction.

Comment: You need to code that on your own, wordpress does not offer anything specifically for such a type of image order out of the box.

Comment: How are you planning on organizing the products? Custom post type?

Comment: @JCL1178  - I created a new table for the meta info about the products. I am organizing each product by product name, then sku (in folders). Currently I am working directly in the DB, not sure how it will be administered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that all you need to do is be able to generate enough rows per item/photo as you need and then use something like CSV importer to import the file and set up the custom taxonomies automatically.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/

The nice thing about this plugin is that it allows you to import with hierarchy so you can keep the structure the way you show it above. The only hang up is what to do about the images.  You could easily make the image appear in the body of the post during the generation of the CSV file and then just FTP all the images and follow it up with the import.  If you need the image to be the Featured Image for gallery display, that should be a pretty quick script to write in Wordpress: scan all posts with a certain taxonomy and set a custom image based on the first image found in the post body.